# Reseve memory for inner vector in a std::vector<std::vector<TYPE>>

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, memory-management

I like to reserve memory for the inner vector in a `std::vector<std::vector<TYPE>>`, in order to avoid a lot of single memory allocations during a subsequent `push_back`. I don't  know the `innerSize` of the vector exactly, but I can give a good estimate.

`std::resize` can be used as

```
vecs.resize(outerSize, std::vector<TYPE>(innerSize));
```

where `outerSize` and `innerSize` are given ints. This does not work for me, because the default constructor is not applicable. However `std::reserve` does not provide an interface like this.

Is this a good way to reserve memory for all inner vectors?

```
vecs.resize(outerSize);
for (auto &elem : vecs) {
    elem.reserve(innerSize);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is a good way.

Comment: Your loop seems the better way. I even think that `vecs.resize(outerSize, vector_with_reserved_size);` is not guaranty to build inner vectors with correct capacity.

Comment: Note that `vecs.resize(outerSize, std::vector<TYPE>(innerSize));` is very different than the `reserve` loop you have. The former will initialize every inner vector with the default constructor. If `TYPE` is large, it will end up taking much longer time than the `reserve` loop. EDIT: And later on you'd have to _replace_ existing `TYPE` items, instead of calling `push_back`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only alternative that I can think of is that you create a wrapper class around the inner `std::vector`; which reserves it on construction.  Leading to something like

```
struct TableRow {
    std::vector<TYPE> data;
    TableRow() {
        data.reserve(SIZE);
    }
}

std::vector<TableRow> myVectorOfVectors;
```

The other gain from this is that your inner vector gets a name that you can understand (such as `TableRow`); but the downside is that unless you're willing to play the game of inheriting `std::vector` (if in doubt; don't do this); your usage of the wrapper class will have to be a little awkward since you'll need to add a `.data` or something of that ilk.

As others have said though; your way is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your attempt is a good solution, if not the best:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::vector<NonDefaultConstructible>> vecs;
vecs.resize(outerSize);
for (auto &elem : vecs) {
    elem.reserve(innerSize);
}
```

The only way to improve it would need a constructor for `std::vector` which would accept a capacity and construct a vector with size zero and provided capacity. Such a constructor [does not exist](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).